# Python pcl_visualization, sirokujira, no method/parameter preview in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to work with a [point cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud) in Python, Visual Studio 2017 and the [Point Cloud Library from Sirokujira](https://github.com/Sirokujira/python-pcl) ([PCL](http://pointclouds.org/)), installed on Windows 10 64 bit and Anaconda 4.4.10 (Python 3.5) with:

```
 conda config --append channels conda-forge
 conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl
```

As I can use methods I do not get a preview of available methods and parameters, and it is rather hard to figure out how to use the methods. Is there a chance to add the missing information into Visual Studio?

Comment: What do you mean by *"As I can use methods I do not get a preview of available methods and parameters"*?

Comment: How is the Sirokujira version different from the Strawlab / John Stower's version? Or in other words, why use Sirokujira's?

Comment: I do an import pcl and import pcl.pcl_visualization. I can e.g. load a cloud (pcd file) with <br>cloud = pcl.PointCloud()<br>cloud.from_file(bytes("test.pcd","ascii")<br><br>Writing cloud. in the code window and hovering the mouse over it I do not get a method list and hovering over cloud.from_file will not show a parameter description

Comment: I do not know the difference between the two libs